# PHP network function gethostname() not working as documented

Tags: php

I want to display the name of the local machine which accesses my webpage. I stumbled upon the PHP network function gethostname(), which supposedly *'gets the standard host name for the local machine.'* (http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php)

So I code:

```
<?php
echo gethostname();
?>
```

I test this, and this is what is displayed:

'freeolaweb0.freeola.co.uk'

Freeola is my internet service provider, so presumably this is why this is shown. However, I interpreted the PHP.net definition to mean that this function returns the name of the local machine (e.g 'My Laptop'), but instead it seems to be returning something which doesn't uniquely identify the local machine (which is what I want).

Am I misconstruing the function's definition? If I am, is there any way to find the name of the local machine which is visiting my webpage?

Comment: PHP is executed server side.

Comment: So what ***is*** your hostname? What are you expecting?

Comment: Ah, so is that the name of the local machine used by my web server?

Comment: I am expecting to see 'DESKTOP-VNA70L3' because that is my local host name (according to the ipconfig command prompt)

Comment: *php > echo gethostname();*
returns *jazzhands* for me, seems to work as expected

Comment: Dan, is it possible that you are testing that with a local server and so it returns the name of the local machine? Whilst if you tested it with a remote server it would return the name of the server's machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the host name of the machine visiting your site you can use:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];
```

Check out this page:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Not an answer to the question. The OP was simply asking about the expected behaviour of a function, not an alternative to one that's not working.

Comment: Here is a quote directly from the question posed - maybe you should read all of it: "Am I misconstruing the function's definition? If I am, is there any way to find the name of the local machine which is visiting my webpage?"

Comment: He is not "misconstruing the function's definition".

Comment: The documentation for $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] says you need to configure my server to allow it to work, but I have no idea how I might go about doing that :/

Comment: This *is* an answer to the follow up question, which assumes the answer is "yes" to the first question. @Nunchy perhaps adding an explanation of what  `gethostname` actually does might make this answer a little clearer to someone just taking a glance.

Comment: I think the person asking the question has some confusion regarding local/remote...the question at the end kind of tells you that, no? Getting the details of the person visiting your site would imply remote as opposed to local, gethostbyname() returns the hostname of the local machine. what's the problem here?

Comment: Oh right, in that case 'gethostname' isn't what I need, I need the name of the remote host (I.e the machine name of the user visiting my webpage). Does $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] return this?

Comment: No problem...if people read the question properly they'd have understood that. The page I linked will probably be a great help to you, best of luck.

Comment: You can use $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] to get the hostname and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to get the IP address of the client.

Comment: returns null...